# On the smallest open Diophantine equations: beyond Hilbert's 10 problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

In 2018, Zidane asked [What is the smallest unsolved Diophantine equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316708/what-is-the-smallest-unsolved-diophantine-equation) The suggested way to measure size of the equation is substitute 2 instead of all variables, absolute values instead of all coefficients, and evaluate.

In the Mathoverlow question [Can you solve the listed smallest open Diophantine equations?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400714/can-you-solve-the-listed-smallest-open-diophantine-equations) I list the current smallest equations for which it is open whether there exists any integer solution at all (Hilbert's 10 problem).

However, there are some famous equations, like $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$ of size $H=2^3+2^3+2^3+3=27$, for which the Hilbert's 10 problem is trivial (in this example, $x=y=z=1$ is a solution), but the equation can hardly be classified as solved, because we do not even know whether the solution set is finite.

Here, I consider more general problem: **for a given polynomial Diophantine equation, determine whether the solution set is finite, and if so, list all the solutions**. This is a much better approximation of our intuition what does it mean to solve an equation, but still avoids a subtle issue what counts as an acceptable description of the solution set if it is infinite (see [What does it mean to solve an equation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410297/what-does-it-mean-to-solve-an-equation) for some discussion of this).

**Selected solved equations.**

- The smallest equation that required a new idea turned out to be $y^2+z^2=x^3-2$ of size $H=18$, see  [Representing $x^3-2$ as a sum of two squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409857/representing-x3-2-as-a-sum-of-two-squares) for the proof that it has infinitely many integer solutions.
- Equations
  $
  y(z^2-y)=x^3+2
  $
  and
  and
  $
  xyz=x^3+y^2-2
  $
  of size $H=22$ has been listed as open and then solved by Tomita, see the answer below.

**Smallest open equations.**

The current smallest open equations are the equations
$$
y^2-yz^2+x^3-2=0
$$
and
$$
xyz=x^3+y^2+2
$$
of size $H=22$. These are the only remaining open equations with $H \leq 22$.

One may also study **equations of special types**. For example, the current smallest open symmetric equation (that is, invariant under cyclic shift of the variables) is
$$
x^2y+y^2z+z^2x=1
$$
of size $H=25$. The current smallest open equations in two variables are
$$
y^3+y=x^4+x
$$
and
$$
y^3-y=x^4-x
$$
of size $H=28$, the current smallest open 3-monomial equation is
$$
x^3y^2=z^3+2
$$
of size $H=42$, while the current smallest open homogeneous equation is
$$
x^4+x^3 y-y^4+y^3 z+z^4=0
$$
of size $H=80$, see [Existence of rational points on some genus 3 curves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444712).

For the listed equations, the Hilbert 10th problem is trivial, because there are some obvious small solutions. **The question**, for each of the listed equations, is whether the solution set is finite or infinite, and if finite, list the solutions.

**The plan** is to list new smallest open equations once these ones are solved. The solved equations will be moved to the "solved" section.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you envisaging using MO to record ongoing progress on this open-ended project? If so, I don't think MO is the right venue for that.

Comment: The question, for each of the listed equations, is whether the solution set is finite or infinite (and if finite, list the solutions).

Comment: I have solved hundreds other equations with $H \leq 22$ but cannot solve these ones. The equations look nice and I hope mathoverflow users will enjoy trying to solve them.

Comment: For the first two, thinking about random $x \approx N^{1/3}, y \approx N^{1/2}, z\approx N^{1/4}$ suggests there should be infinitely many solutions on $1/2 + 1/3 +1/4>1$.  For the last two,  $x \approx N^{1/3}, y \approx N^{1/2}, z\approx N^{1/6}$ suggests there may be infinitely many but it should be harder to show as $1/2 + 1/3+1/6=1$.

Comment: One of the integer solution of the equation $xyz=x^3+y^2-2$  is 
$(x,y,z)=(-5629441, -14347779969589, 2548702)$ with $|x|,|z|<10^{7}$.

Comment: Yes, there are many small solutions, like $(x,y,z)=(1,1,-1)$, but some large solutions as well, as predicted by heuristic argument.

Comment: @TimothyChow These are interesting questions and discussions,aren’t they? I would like to understand why this might not be the right venue,since I might have posed such a question without hesitation…so I might need to learn something?

Comment: @EGME It's okay if there's a fixed list of equations. But if every time someone solves one of the equations, the equation gets deleted and replaced with a new one, then that's a kind of dynamic evolution that I don't think is suitable for MO.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thank you for the opinion. The equations are never deleted, just moved to the solved section, so that it is clear which equations are solved and which are not. If all equations are solved, I think it is nicer to put new ones in the same question rather than create a new question of the same spirit. But, in any case, once easier equations are solved, I expect further "dynamic" will be minimal.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thank you very much for your opinion. It is helpful to understand this.

Comment: @TimothyChow Perhaps there ought to be a companion site to MO, something like MO-discussions which is more dynamic. Now this is not the same as chat, which is even more dynamic, as the name implies. It just means that a thread can evolve … I see a need for this kind of a site where interesting mathematics can be discussed; and, since it would be a research level discussion, making mistakes would be a bit more acceptable … what do you think?

Comment: @EGME This might be a good discussion for [meta.mathoverflow.net](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: For the two-variable equations, I think finiteness should follow from Siegel's theorem. The open symmetric equation is a smooth cubic surface that is smooth at infinity, thus perhaps should be similar to the $x^3+y^3+z^3=n$ equations, i..e infinitely many solutions, with very rapidly-increasing size, and no plausible method to prove it has infinitely many with current technology.

Comment: Yes, for the 2-variable equations we know that the solution set is finite, and the problem is to find all solutions. For the symmetric equation, we know that there are infinitely many integer solutions to $x^3+y^3+z^3=1$, so maybe there is a relatively easy proof for this equation as well.

Answer (score 11):

This is a partial solution.  The equation

$$y(z^2-y)=x^3+2\tag{1}$$

has infinitely many integer solutions.

Since $y = 1/2z^2 \pm 1/2\sqrt{z^4-4x^3-8}$, the expression $z^4-4x^3-8$ must be a perfect square. On the other hand, substitute $x=-3n^2-2n-2$ and $z=3n+1$ to $z^4-4x^3-8$, then we get
$$z^4-4x^3-8 = (25+8n+12n^2)(1+2n+3n^2)^2,$$
where $n$ is arbitrary integer. Hence we must find integer solutions of $$v^2 = 25+8n+12n^2\tag{2}.$$ We know equation $(2)$ has infinitely many integer solutions (Gauss's theorem, Mordell's book p.57). Recursive solutions are given as follows.
\begin{align*}(v_0,n_0)&=(\pm 5,0),\\
(v_{k+1},n_{k+1}) &= (7v_k + 24n_k + 8,2v_n + 7n_k + 2).\end{align*}

```
             k      x     y     z
            [12],[-458, 10510, 37]  
            [12],[-458, -9141, 37]
            [172],[-89098, 26729099, 517] 
            [172],[-89098, -26461810, 517] 
            [2400],[-17284802, 71887487358, 7201]  
            [2400],[-17284802, -71835632957, 7201]
            [33432],[-3353162738, 194174947774195, 100297]  
            [33432],[-3353162738, -194164888285986, 100297]
            [465652],[-650496286618, 524648022526642094, 1396957]  
            [465652],[-650496286618, -524646071037782245, 1396957]
            [-8],[-178, 2654, 23]  
            [-8],[-178, -2125, 23]
            [-108],[-34778, 6538075, 323]  
            [-108],[-34778, -6433746, 323]
            [-1500],[-6747002, 17535455598, 4499]  
            [-1500],[-6747002, -17515214597, 4499]
            [-20888],[-1308883858, 47355417946259, 62663]  
            [-20888],[-1308883858, -47351491294690, 62663]
            [-290928],[-253916721698, 127949397813283390, 872783]  
            [-290928],[-253916721698, -127948636063118301, 872783]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have now moved this equation to the "solved" section! One small question - how you have found the expressions of $x$ and $z$ in terms of $n$? Just computer search for quadratic expressions with small coefficients?

Comment: Yes,　since this equation has many small solutions, I thought it would be reduced to quadratic diophantine equation problem.

Comment: Actually, the same method solves another equation, $xyz=x^3+y^2-2$. We need $D=x^2z^2-4x^3+8$ to be a perfect square. Select $x=6n^2+1$ and $z=6n$, then $D=4(6n^2-1)^2(3n^2+1)$. It is left to note that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $3n^2+1$ is a perfect square. I will now move this equation to the "solved" section as well! So, there are currently two equations left with $H\leq 22$.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk which?

Comment: $y(z^2-y)=x^3-2$ and $xyz=x^3+y^2+2$, as stated in the question.